# Rotation distorts the polygon after several transformations

Tags: python, geometry, rotation, 2d

Trying to rotate a polygon using [basic geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_two_dimensions). Code for reproduction:

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def rotate_origin_only(xy, radians):
    x, y = xy
    xx = x * math.cos(radians) - y * math.sin(radians)
    yy = x * math.sin(radians) + y * math.cos(radians)

    return xx, yy


Figure = np.array(((0, 8), (8, -8), (0, 0), (-8, -8)))

plt.fill(*list(zip(*Figure)))
for i in range(7):
    temp = []
    for point in Figure:
        temp.append(rotate_origin_only(point, math.radians(30) * i))
    plt.fill(*list(zip(*temp)))

plt.show()

plt.fill(*list(zip(*Figure)))
for i in range(7):
    for i, point in enumerate(Figure):
        Figure[i] = rotate_origin_only(point, math.radians(30))
    plt.fill(*list(zip(*Figure)))

plt.show()
```

Output 1 (is as expected):
[image: as expected, the polygon rotates]
Output 2 (is completely unexpected):
[image]
Why is the second one distorted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After almost three years, coming back, I finally solved the mystery. This is expected (though questionable) behaviour of numpy:

- When assigning a tuple (even of floats) to an int ndarray (was implicitly defined as int because all my numbers were integers), numpy implicitly casts the tuple into integers, rounding them. This obviously caused massive distortions in the rotations.

That means, replacing

```
np.array(((0, 8), (8, -8), (0, 0), (-8, -8)))
```

with

```
np.array(((0, 8), (8, -8), (0, 0), (-8, -8)), dtype=float)
```

solves the problem.

Also note, that in the second output there is one more rotation applied, because first `range` includes rotating by `0` degrees

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you miss a `* i` in the first algorithm.
In the first algorithm:

```py
Figure[i] = rotate_origin_only(point, math.radians(33))
```

In the second:

```py
temp.append(rotate_origin_only(point, math.radians(33 * i)))
```

Also, you are using `i` twice in the nested for-loop. This is a bad coding practice and can cause confusion. Commonly the second loop variable is called `j`, like so:

```py
for i in range(7):
    for j, point in enumerate(Figure):
```

Comment: I didn't put * i in the first algorithm cause I rotated one figure many times, while in the second algorithm I rotated the initial figure every time by more deegrees

Comment: @user9943698 Okay, maybe your rotation itself is not correct. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_two_dimensions) the new coordinates are: `xx = x * math.cos(radians) - y * math.sin(radians)
yy = x * math.sin(radians) + y * math.cos(radians)`. I guess this caused the unexpected outcome.